# iPad app to take notes in mathematics

Tags: ipad, pdf, notes.app

I would like to take mathematical notes with my iPad so that at the end of the process I would have a PDF file of A4 pages.

Do you have any idea?

PS: I have tried Nebo but it is too complicated to type a whole page of mathematics.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request

Comment: MyScript MathPad is a great option.

Comment: @circle : I dont need the transformation types

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Noteshelf 2](http://www.noteshelf.net) or [GoodNotes](http://www.goodnotesapp.com). Both are not explicitly math-apps, but really good note-taking tools. You can export all your notes as PDF and even import PDFs or pictures in a note